# VLookup with empty cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here are my 2 columns

```
A       B
Spain   [EMPTY]
France  Euros
Spain   Euros
```

In another cell, I would like to write a formula that would write the currency of each country. like if I have:

C1=Spain, C2=France,
I would want to have
D1=Euros, D2=Euros.

I tried it with `VLOOKUP`, but it gave me
C1=[Empty], C2=Euros

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Um... why is spain listed twice once empty and once with currency?  Eliminate the empty and problem solved...

Comment: xQbert told you the solution. An explanation for the record: VLOOKUP will return the **first** matching value (which is empty here for Span)

Comment: Well actually I gave an example of a short list. But my list has 10'000+ values and it has many times empty values as currencies (as we do not have the information). To be complete, I then put the top 10 expenses in countries and want to associate their respective currencies

Comment: I thought it was quite a reasonable question as is. Either it can be solved for (a) immediately with a formula (as this question asks) (b) immediately with VBA, or (c) formula/VBA is used to fill in the blanks on the data set.

Comment: @brettdj  true enough but if duplicates are allowed it brings into question the possibility of having England with "Euros" and England with the "pound"  so then which one would I select from VLookup.  So my original question of Why is spain listed twice still is valid but I'll postulate a answer without knowing the requirements anyway.

Comment: No, the problem is understated. The OP has not told us what he wants to do with duplicates, empty or otherwise.

Comment: SammyDow, I suggest you look at Barry's response

Comment: @TomalekGeret'kal The OP *did not mention* duplicates in the original question, and has since accepted the answer as solving the problem. So it surprises me that you want to raise an issue where there clearly isnt one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have commented, `VLOOKUP` will return the first match it finds, thats why you get `[EMPTY]` for `Spain`.
You can work around this by adding an intermediate column.  Lets assume you insert a column `B` with formula `=IF(C1="","",A1)` and copy down for all used rows.

Column D is `Spain`, `France` etc

Column E is now `=VLOOKUP(D1,B:C,2,0)`

Comment: option (c). Significantly easier than my option (a) and hence a more practical - read superior - way forward. But I was keen to meet the column D challenge ....

Comment: This option worked perfectly. This is awesome! Thank you so much for your quick help! Beyond the fact that it helped me solve my problem, it also makes me improve my Excel skills

Comment: Simple and elegant.  Basically says, if the currency is blank, blank out the country so that vlookup will only match those countries that are not blank. +1

Comment: It's not elegant, because the original problem is not elegant; this is a hacky workaround to broken data!

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal this is an unfair comment on a sound solution, your view having been built upon your false premise that the original data was - as you have put it - *broken*.

Comment: @brettdj: Oh, don't get me wrong, the solution is perfect for the stated question. But because the problem is not elegant, the solution kind of inherits that. And your assertion that my premise is false is as baseless as my premise ;)

Answer (score 2):

IF you can SORT your columns, sort by Column A then by B descending (Z-A) then use the vlookup you're trying to use.  THis will put the country with a value 1st so V-Lookup will return a vale instead of empty.  When empty is returned, its becuase EVERY single instance of that entry in column A has an empty value.  However if the entry in A has Multiple values, it will pick the first from descending order.

So do you have situations in which a entry in column A has multiple values beyond 1 currency and a blank entry?

However this has a pitfall in that the Order now matters so if data is added to this spreadsheet a reorder must occur each time.

Comment: I am trying one by one all the useful approaches that have been sent on this post. I will let you know once I have tried it but thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: Dear Qbert, to answer you, the only options are either the currency or a blank entry. So your method would work. However, Whenever I sort my columns differently (my file has more than a 100 columns), the results will change and will thus bring us back to the same problem of empty results, am I right ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. that is the pitfall I was attempting to describe. chris's solution is by far the most elegant and provides the greatest flexability

Answer (score 1):

I'm more a VBA than formula guy but this (horrible!) array formula will return the first non blank match

in D1 put
`=IF(MAX(IF(--(A$1:A$6=C1)*LEN(B$1:B$6)>0,ROW(A$1:A$6),0))>0,INDEX(B$1:B$6,MAX(IF(--(A$1:A$6=C1)*LEN(B$1:B$6)>0,ROW(A$1:A$6),0))),"no match")`
and press Shift - Ctrl - Enter together

how it works

- `IF(--(A$1:A$6=C1)*LEN(B$1:B$6)>0,ROW(A$1:A$6),0))` checks that A1 matches each of A1 to A6, and correspondingly whether B1 to B6 is non-empty.
- If both these conditions are `TRUE` then the row number of these matches is placed in an array, if `FALSE` the formula returns zero. so the first array id {0,0,3,0,0,0}
- If the `MAX` of this array is not zero then the formula returns this cell position from the B column using `INDEX` in `INDEX(B$1:B$6,MAX(IF(--(A$1:A$6=C1)*LEN(B$1:B$6)>0,ROW(A$1:A$6),0)))`
- Else there is "no match"

I will shoot this to a formula genius called Barry Houdini to see how much he can shorten it

Enlarged sample (including a true blank result) below

[image]

Comment: A little shorter version (assuming Excel 2007+): `=IFERROR(INDEX(B$1:B$6,MAX(IF(--(A$1:A$6=C3)*LEN(B$1:B$6)>0,ROW(A$1:A$6),-1))),"no match")`

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. I am astonished by how fast some of you guys can come up with answers, I hope that one day I'll have these skills. Unfortunately, when I use it, I get the "No match" value, even when I press SHIFT - CTRL - ENTER together. Could it be because of the fact that in my file, the C column is the result of : INDEX('TCD City'!$B$6:$C$949;Y19;1) ? I am not explaining it very clearly, is there any way to add my Excel file ?

Comment: I am trying your comment's function and will get back to you as soon as it is done

Comment: @chrisneilsen nicely done. Even for xl2003 compliance I think my current effort could be significantly shortened

Comment: @sammydow I suggest you go with the working column from Chris, or the sorted order by xQbert. Most people will find them much simpler than arrays. If you do have x07/10 and you want to go the array route use the formula from Chris above.

Comment: I do not know why, but I get the "no match" result. It might be because my file is more "complicated" than the examples I gave and that I should add something that I did not grasp. However, the other method you sent me is perfect ! Thank you again !

Answer (score 1):

I feel like a fraud here.....don't ask me any VBA questions!

I note that use of `MAX` actually means that your formula (and chris' amended version) actually gives the **last** non-blank match. You can also do that with a non-CSE `LOOKUP` formula, i.e.

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(B$2:B$6<>"")/(A$2:A$6=C1),B$2:B$6)`

which will return #N/A if there's no match

for the text "no match" instead then, assuming formula returns text values you can use 2003 compatible

`=LOOKUP("zzz",IF({1,0},"No match",LOOKUP(2,1/(B$2:B$6<>"")/(A$2:A$6=C1),B$2:B$6)))`

For **first** non-blank match you can use `INDEX/MATCH` in a similar way, i.e.

`=INDEX(B$2:B$6,MATCH(1,(B$2:B$6<>"")*(A$2:A$6=C1),0))`

confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: +1 @BarryHoudini I knew I'd created a formulastein! Thanks for taking the time to post this comprehensive solution.